# Delete from C_t_data for Bi Extractor

Tags: abap, sap-bw, sap-erp

Trying to delete unwanted records from extractor Badi logic. Due to performance reasons, I want to run extractor for only one company code.

Can we use this below?

```
Delete c_t_data where bukrs NE t_cc.
```

`t_cc` is a variable that stores company code information.

`c_t_data` is of type extract structure of `0fi_gl_14` datasource.

Does this sound alright?

Comment: don't re-post please your [badly formulated questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601325/delete-from-c-t-data) another time, better learn [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just edit/improve your closed question. If it's okay, it will be re-opened. People can still comment/help you on a closed question to clarify the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you saying badly formulated in sap terms these are the only thing known to me to share with someone to get appropriate answers ..anyways..the other question was closed and I wasnt getting any response so I thought of creating other with more information. If someone in SAP world they know what I'm talking about